# Click on a specific text in a table

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Always when I register a user, It's shown in a table on the last page (currently I have 4 pages of registered users), so I need to go to the last page and click this user created

**My code:**

**Locators used**

```
class FeeScheduleLocators(object):

  ADD_BUTTON = (By.ID, "save")
  NAME = (By.ID, "id_name")
  SAVE_BUTTON = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='submit']")
  FEE_SCHEDULE_LIST = (By.TAG_NAME, "td")
  NEXT_LINK = (By.LINK_TEXT, "Next")
```

**Method used**

```
def create_fee_schedule(self):

    self.name = fake.name()

    self.find_element(FeeScheduleLocators.NAME).send_keys(self.name)

    self.find_element(FeeScheduleLocators.SAVE_BUTTON).click()
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, AUTOCOMPLETE_TIMEOUT).until(
        EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CLASS_NAME, "success"), 'Fee added sucessfully'))

    self.fee_list = self.find_elements(FeeScheduleLocators.FEE_SCHEDULE_LIST)

    for self.each_register in self.fee_list:

        while self.each_register.text != self.name:

            self.find_element(FeeScheduleLocators.NEXT_LINK).click()
            time.sleep(2)

        else:

            each_register.click()
```

**My problem after run**

The test click just to the second page and shows the error below:

```
E   StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
E     (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
E     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.3 x86_64)
```

**Expected behavior:**

go to the last page and click the name of the user created recently

Comment: Can you post a link to the page? Also, please explain what you are trying to accomplish with this code. I'm having a hard time understanding the intent. What is clicking on the desired TD supposed to do? Can you not search for the desired TD directly instead of looping through the list? What does clicking the next link do? Change pages or ?

Comment: @JeffC I edited the description, see if you understand the code. Otherwise, let me know. Thanks a lot. Unfortunately the page is locally

Answer (score 0):

From your description, the desired name should always be on the last page. Your code is looking for the desired name before you've reached the last page.

Instead of using a `for` loop and `while-else`, use a `while` loop to click the Next link as long as it exists. Once it no longer exists, you know that you are on the last page. Then click on the last name or find the desired element directly and click it. You should be able to craft a locator to find the exact element you want but you would need to provide the relevant HTML.